# Why can't datagridview rowcount property be equal to zero?

Tags: datagridview, delphi-prism, rowcount, oxygene

I have datagridview on my winform and you can add and delete items from it. Although I am able to do that successfully, it acts weird.

It requires that its property RowCount be set to 1 or greater. Thus, there is always a single row of grid displayed at all time even when there is no item added to it.

How do you overcome this shortcoming? or Is there a way around it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design if you have `AllowUserToAddRows` set to true.

From MSDN, [DataGridView.RowCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount.aspx) Property:

> If AllowUserToAddRows is true, you cannot set RowCount to 0. In this
>   case, call the DataGridViewRowCollection.Clear method to remove all
>   rows except the row for new records. Calling Clear has the same result
>   as setting RowCount to 1 in this case, but is much faster.

When you want to set your RowCount to 0 you can set `AllowUserToAddRows` to false and then back to true when you want to allow your users to add rows.

Comment: Jay Riggs - Fantastic my friend. Your answer is what I needed. It works like a charm. Thank you.